# Copy values that are greater than 0

Tags: excel, vba

Im copying data from workbook to another with the code below. I want to copy customer details and the products with values > 0. Currently my macro is copying all the product columns in a row.
Any ideas how to solve this?

```
Sub copysales()
Dim wb As New Workbook, rowToCopy As Integer
Dim lRow As Integer, nRow As Integer, rowno As Integer, colno As Integer

Set wb = Workbooks("Product.xlsx")
lRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

nRow = wb.Sheets("Sales").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

rowToCopy = nRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For rowno = 2 To lRow

If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q" & rowno) = "Close (won)" Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q" & rowno) = "Close (part-won)") _
    And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & rowno) > 0 And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("T" & rowno) = Date - 1 Then
        For colno = 72 To 79
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowno, colno) <> "" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & rowno).Copy wb.Sheets("Sales").Range("A" & rowToCopy) 'To copy sales person name
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & rowno).Copy wb.Sheets("Sales").Range("B" & rowToCopy) 'To copy customer name
                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & rowno).Copy wb.Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & rowToCopy) 'To copy legal number
                  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q" & rowno).Copy wb.Sheets("Sales").Range("F" & rowToCopy) 'To copy status
                   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P" & rowno).Copy wb.Sheets("Sales").Range("G" & rowToCopy) 'To copy sales type
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, colno).Copy wb.Sheets("Sales").Range("H" & rowToCopy) 'To copy product name
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowno, colno).Copy
                wb.Sheets("Sales").Range("E" & rowToCopy).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  'To copy product value
                rowToCopy = rowToCopy + 1
        

    End If
    Next
    End If
    Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy just the cells where product value is > 0, check for that criteria where you currently check that the product value cell has content (`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowno, colno) <> ""`)

Something perhaps like the following.  Reformatted the code and made some changes to improve readability.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copysales()
    Dim rowToCopy As Integer
    Dim lRow As Integer, nRow As Integer, rowno As Integer, colno As Integer

    'Repeatedly calling the lengthy expression 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")' to reference Sheet1
    'makes the code harder to read and can negatively impact speed if there is a large number of rows
    Dim wrkSheet1 As Worksheet
    Set wrkSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        
    'Repeatedly calling the lengthy expression 'wb.Sheets("Sales")' to reference the 'Sales' worksheet
    'makes the code harder to read and can negatively impact speed if there is a large number of rows
    Dim wrkSheetSales As Worksheet
    Set wrkSheetSales = Workbooks("Product.xlsx").Sheets("Sales")
    
    lRow = wrkSheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    nRow = wrkSheetSales.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    rowToCopy = nRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For rowno = 2 To lRow
        
        If IsRowOfInterest(wrkSheet1, rowno) Then
        
            For colno = 72 To 79
                If HasValueOfInterest(wrkSheet1.Cells(rowno, colno)) Then
                    wrkSheet1.Range("K" & rowno).Copy wrkSheetSales.Range("A" & rowToCopy) 'To copy sales person name
                    wrkSheet1.Range("D" & rowno).Copy wrkSheetSales.Range("B" & rowToCopy) 'To copy customer name
                    wrkSheet1.Range("E" & rowno).Copy wrkSheetSales.Range("C" & rowToCopy) 'To copy legal number
                    wrkSheet1.Range("Q" & rowno).Copy wrkSheetSales.Range("F" & rowToCopy) 'To copy status
                    wrkSheet1.Range("P" & rowno).Copy wrkSheetSales.Range("G" & rowToCopy) 'To copy sales type
                    wrkSheet1.Cells(1, colno).Copy wrkSheetSales.Range("H" & rowToCopy) 'To copy product name
                    wrkSheet1.Cells(rowno, colno).Copy
                    wrkSheetSales.Range("E" & rowToCopy).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'To copy product value
                    rowToCopy = rowToCopy + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

'This function checks the criteria for copying the data
Private Function HasValueOfInterest(ByVal valueRange As Range) As Boolean
    HasValueOfInterest = False
On Error GoTo ErrorExit
    'Not sure how the value is formatted and stored in Sheet1 (String or Number).
    'The error handling (On Error GoTo ErrorExit) ensures False is returned when CDbl() operates on a cell value that is not a number
    HasValueOfInterest = valueRange.Value <> "" And CDbl(valueRange.Value2) > 0#
    Exit Function

ErrorExit:    
End Function

'Added to improve readability of the 'copysales' subroutine
Private Function IsRowOfInterest(ByVal wrkSheet As Worksheet, ByVal rowno As Integer) As Boolean
    IsRowOfInterest = _
        (wrkSheet.Range("Q" & rowno) = "Close (won)" _
            Or wrkSheet.Range("Q" & rowno) = "Close (part-won)") _
        And wrkSheet.Range("K" & rowno) > 0 _
        And wrkSheet.Range("T" & rowno) = Date - 1
End Function
```